# Apple ID Not Working To Reset Password

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-id, password

My laptop wasn't charging for a while, so I forgot the password for it. I went to log back in, and when I remembered I forgot the password, I went to reset it with my apple id, all the info was correct, I even changed the pass and email used, but it still wasn't working. I'm not sure what to do. I have a Mac Book Air.

Answer (score 10):

You can reset your user password directly from your MacBook Air.

**Resetting password from Recovery Mode**

To reset your password from Recovery Mode, follow these steps:

1. Power off your Mac
2. Boot into Recovery Mode by pressing the power button while holding down <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>
3. If prompted, select your language and press <kbd>enter</kbd>
4. Choose Utilities > Terminal.
5. Enter resetpassword (all one word, lowercase letters)
6. Press <kbd>Return</kbd>
7. Select the drive with your account (typically the main drive)
8. Choose your account using Select the User Account.
9. Enter a new password
10. Re-enter the same password
11. Enter a password hint
12. Click Save
13. Ignore the warning about the password changing
14. Click OK.
15. Shutdown the Mac using Apple > Shut Down
16. Restart the Mac normally and use the new password to log into your account

Let me know how you go or if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I am not sure why but the official guide to reset password is not working fine as your guide does. Thank you for helping as I cannot login immediately after trying to setup and logged out my MBP. I guess I broke the record of fastest forgot password world record

Comment: Does this mean that someone else can get into my MacBook user account by following this procedure?

Comment: Whether or not this *exact* procedure could be used by someone to get into your Mac user account depends on your setup. Generally, though, there are a number of ways people *could* get into a user's account on a Mac (or Windows PC, for that matter). And there are a number of options people can take to secure their data (e.g. linking your account to your Apple ID). You may find [this](https://support.apple.com/HT204756) of interest as well.